# How to get rid of "Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005e a=-1}"

Tags: java, android, menu

I am Trying to Create a RecyclerView with PopUp Menu but whenever I try to access popup menu it crushes and says :  **Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005e a=-1}**

My menu.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="Menu 1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:title="Menu 2" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:title="Menu 3" />


</menu>
```

style.xml:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- your theme inherits from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- theme customizations -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#c21d1111</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#c6897929</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Adapter Class:

```
/**
 * Created by User on 21-Apr-17.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MyList> list;
    private Context mCtx;

    public CustomAdapter(List<MyList> list, Context mCtx) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyList myList = list.get(position);
        holder.textViewHead.setText(myList.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getDesc());

        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //handle menu2 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                //handle menu3 click
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            buttonViewOption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
   04-20 17:36:06.311 10660-10660/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
04-20 17:36:32.171 10660-10675/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust E/EGL_emulation: tid 10675: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-20 17:36:32.171 10660-10675/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf13f21e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
04-20 17:36:33.147 10660-10660/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust D/ViewRootImpl[MyOtherActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=true
04-20 17:36:33.944 10660-10660/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust D/ViewRootImpl[MyOtherActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
04-20 17:36:49.733 10660-10660/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-20 17:36:49.733 10660-10660/com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust, PID: 10660
                                                                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005e a=-1}
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005e a=-1}
                                                                               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:761)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7035)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7216)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:439)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:370)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:369)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233)
                                                                               at com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:71)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hridoy.user.ieee_aust"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: import **import android.widget.PopupMenu;**

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by pass instance the activity instead of the context to PopupMenu();